# Call Activity from BaseGameActirity

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am developing a game using andengine so I am extending my main activity from BaseGameActivity. I have also implemented SceneManager. now from within scenemanager, I want to call a class that extends 'Activity' (not BaseGameActivity)
I am using following code to call the class from my SceneManager

```
class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity
{
 // code
 // implemented SceneManager
}

class SceneManager
{
  BaseGameActivity activity;

  public void showFbActivity()
  {
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, FbConnect.class)); // Error line
  }
}

class MainMenuScene
{
    public boolean onMenuItemClicked(MenuScene pMenuScene, IMenuItem pMenuItem,
        float pMenuItemLocalX, float pMenuItemLocalY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return false;
      switch(pMenuItem.getID())
      {
      case MENU_PLAY:
        SceneManager.getInstance().loadGameScene(engine);
        return true;
      case MENU_OPTIONS:
        SceneManager.getInstance().showFbActivity();
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
      }
  }
}

class FbConnect extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

now my problem is that I am getting a nullpointerexception on the above mentioned line (see commented code).

following is my logcat output
commented line in above code is line# 118 in SceneManager.

```
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2857)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at com.sohi.tech.rollball.SceneManager.showFbActivity(SceneManager.java:118)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at com.sohi.tech.rollball.MainMenuScene.onMenuItemClicked(MainMenuScene.java:93)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.menu.MenuScene.onAreaTouched(MenuScene.java:139)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onAreaTouchEvent(Scene.java:413)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onSceneTouchEvent(Scene.java:357)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.CameraScene.onSceneTouchEvent(CameraScene.java:64)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onChildSceneTouchEvent(Scene.java:420)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onSceneTouchEvent(Scene.java:338)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchScene(Engine.java:452)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchEvent(Engine.java:438)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController$TouchEventRunnablePoolItem.run(BaseTouchController.java:102)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:54)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:1)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler.onUpdate(PoolUpdateHandler.java:88)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController.onUpdate(BaseTouchController.java:62)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:584)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:56)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
09-14 22:52:32.035: E/AndroidRuntime(22385):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line to

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(BaseGameActivity.this, FbConnect.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent it = new Intent(BaseGameActivity.this, FbConnect.class);
activity.startActivity(it);
```

Comment: My SceneManager class doesn't extend from anything so BaseGameActivity is not recognized inside it. changing the code to your suggested code shows an error "No enclosing instance of the type BaseGameActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: Fixed. I called FBconnect.class from MainMenuScene instead of calling it through scenemanager.